# Puedo definir una zona horaria personalizada en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Resulta que necesito definir una zona horaria `UTC+01:30`, y no encuentro ningún pais por la zona de Europa.

Unos de los más cercanos es `Europa/London`, pero me faltan 30 minutos.

Cabe aclarar que estoy utilizando Carbon para las fechas, si hay alguna forma de aplicar estos 30 minutos que me falta aunque sea en código, escucho alternativas.

Comment: Si pero tendria que usar addMinute cada vez que tenga que usar fecha y cualquier mantenimiento seria un caos..

Answer (score 2):

Primero:

- Dentro de tu app, en la carpeta config y en el archivo app.php, en la clave `timezone` establece una [zona horaria válida](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Si la intención es que la hora aparezca siempre formateada cuando se retorne, entonces puedes:

- Declarar un [accesor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) en el modelo relativo

  - Dentro del accesor vamos a retornar el valor parseado
  - Al valor parseado le agregamos los minutos deseados con el método `addMinutes(cantidadDeseada)`

Código:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return now()::parse($value)->addMinutes(40);
}
```

Ahora cuando invoques en la vista a dicho metodo de esta forma:

```
{{ $data->created_at }}
```

Sin el accesor ontendriamos por ejemplo:

> 2020-07-16 17:10:14

Posterior implementando el accesor:

> 2020-07-16 17:50:14

Comment: y si lo agregan en el services provider.

Comment: @Shassain honestamente no lo habia considerado, si gustas aportarle al OP adelante

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar con lo siguiente:

Crea la carptea `app\Helpers` y crea una nueva clase `Carbona`(solo es por falta de imaginacion), que contendría lo siguiente:

```
<?php    
namespace App\Helpers;    
use Collective\Html\FormFacade;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class Carbona
{
    public function ahora(){
        return Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30);
    }
}
```

Que es donde agregas los minutos que deseas.

Luego creas otra carpeta `app\Facades` y creas otra clase con el mismo nombre `Carbona`, pero este contendría lo siguiente:

```
<?php
namespace App\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
class Carbona extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'ahora';
    }
}
```

Esto quedaría de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tomes en cuenta las clases: Helpers y Forms son solo míos.

El siguiente paso es abrir tu archivo `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` y agregar codigo en la funcion `register`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
            /*quiza tengas mas codigo aqui no lo borres*/
use App\Helpers\Carbona;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /*quiza teengas mas codigo aqui no lo borres*/
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        /*quiza teengas mas codigo aqui no lo borres*/

        //agregas las siguientes lineas
        \App::bind('ahora', function()
        {
            return new Carbona();
        });    
    }
}
```

El ultimo paso es agregar el facade a tus `aliases` en `config\app.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
    'timezone' => 'America/La_Paz',// espero que y hayas intentado editar esta linea segun tu ciudad
    'locale' => 'en',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
    'providers' => [
        ...,
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,/*descomenta esta linea si la tienes comentada*/
    ],

    'aliases' => [
        ...,
        'Carbona' => App\Facades\Carbona::class,//agregas esto a la lista.
    ],

];
```

Después de todo esto podria ser necesario un `composer dumpautoload`, pero en general ya deberia de estar lista para utilizarla en tu controlador asi:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbona;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $fecha_actual=Carbona::ahora();
        /*Puedes aplicarle cualquier tipo de funcion perteneciente a carbon*/
    }
}
```

Y en tus vistas lo puedes utilizar también:

```
{{Carbona::ahora()->toDateTimeString()}}
```

Ohhhh, que bien, esto funciona!!!

> Lo malo es que los `create_at` y `update_at` de las tablas en la base de datos no serán afectados, .